# How to make python code read a certain line of text in a .txt file?

Tags: python

So i have been fiddling around with python and league of legends. And i found out you can make notes in game. So i thought about making python code read a line of text from the note i made in game, like "Lux no flash", but it doesn't  seems to be able to read it at all, it only works when i do it manually with the exact same code. Here is my code:

```
import os
import time
def main():
    os.chdir('C:\\Riot Games\\League of Legends\\RADS\\solutions\\lol_game_client_sln\\releases\\0.0.1.237')
    f=open("MyNotes.txt", "r")
    if f.mode == 'r':
        lines=f.readlines()
        text = lines[4]
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if text == 'Lux no flash':
           print('Done')
        else:
            print('Something went wrong')
    f.close()
if __name__== "__main__":
 main()
```

The output is "something went wrong", but when i do it manually it says "done". I feel like python cant read league code. Maybe you guys know how to do this... This is the .txt file im trying to access:

```
##################################################
2018-09-13_18-57-33_
##################################################
Lux no flash
```

Comment: Lux with big or small `L` is what makes your code not work I think

Comment: I found that its the hashes but i'm not certain, the code doesn't care about case and if it is the hashes i need a fix xD

Comment: 1) with `.readlines()`, the line separator is preserved in the resulting strings, so you need to look for `'Lux no flash\n'`; 2) lists are zero-indexed, so this line is at position 3, not 4

Comment: @JohnClarkson I agree this should not retrieve the line if cases do not match and not using any `.lower()` to compare

Comment: What do you mean "the code doesn't care about case"? `==` certaintly is case-sensitive.

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn Yeah the example iv'e given it doesn't show the open line on top, but there is an extra line on top, so it would be 0 - blank, 1  - hash, 2 - random stuff, 3 - hash, 4 - text i typed

Comment: @vash_the_stampede i made sure every case matched when i tested it, so i ruled out that problem in the beginning(In my example i made a mistake when typing, mb)

Comment: @JohnClarkson in your example the file contains `lux` and your search contains `Lux`, by your example it should not retrieve unless there is more code not shown or the file contains `Lux`

Comment: Nice that edit makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lux.txt`:

```
##################################################
2018-09-13_18-57-33_
##################################################
Lux no flash
```

Code:

```
content = []
with open('lux.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        content.append(line.strip('\n'))

    for i in content:
        if 'Lux no flash' == i:
            print("Done")
        else:
            pass
```

**Better** @pygo

```
with open('lux.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    if 'Lux no flash' in content:
        print("Done")
    else:
        print("No else, this works :)")
```

Output:

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 lux.py
> Done
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I'm Just taking a file on an assumption  basis:

> ```
> # cat MyNotes.txt
> there is Lux no flash in line
> there is Something went wrong
> There is nothing lux no flash
> this is all test
> ```

So, just looking for the word `'Lux no flash'` you are searching into your file, we can simply do as below.. but its case sensitive.

It's always best practice to use `with open()` method to read a file.

```
import os
import time
def main():
       with open("MyNotes.txt") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if 'Lux no flash' in line:
                print('Done')
            else:
                print('Something went wrong')
if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Output result will be :

> ```
> Done
> Something went wrong
> Something went wrong
> Something went wrong
> ```

Even tried using the `lux.txt` , it works as expected with my code.

> ```
> import os
> import time
> def main():
>     with open("lux.txt") as f:
>         for line in f.readlines():
>             #line = line.strip()  # use can use the strip() or strip("\n")
>             #line = line.strip("\n") # if you see white spaces in the file
>             if 'Lux no flash' in line:
>                 print('Done')
>             else:
>                 pass
> if __name__== "__main__":
>     main()
> ```

Resulted outout is:

```
# test.py
Done
```